# Making a series of child TeX files and including them as "chapters" in a parent file?

Tags: pdf, standalone

I want to build a big PDF of multiple TeX files which will all have the same preamble. They'll have `\newcommand` and `\renewcommand` as well as `\usepackage` and `\documentclass` because each file should be standalone and compiled as a smaller PDF. But then, I want to take all of the files we have and put them in a main document. I've looked at the other questions:

- [Include file with preamble to another tex file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102598/include-file-with-preamble-to-another-tex-file)
- [Make a .tex file that combines complete .tex documents in subdirectories](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21997/make-a-tex-file-that-combines-complete-tex-documents-in-subdirectories)
- [Outsourcing TikZ code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79594/outsourcing-tikz-code)
- [Manual for the `standalone` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf) on CTAN

and the standalone package. I'm not sure I'll be able to do what I want with these.

Each child document needs to stand on it's own, with it's own preamble, and table of contents, etc. But they should be included in a master document with a global table of contents that ignores/copies all preambles.

---

Below is example code for one of the children files.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts,amssymb,latexsym, multirow}
\usepackage{fullpage, graphicx, subfig, float, hyperref, enumerate}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{pdflscape}%for large figures
\usepackage{cancel}

\linespread{1.3}

\hypersetup{backref,  
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,  
    colorlinks=true}

\renewcommand{\dag}{^\dagger}
\renewcommand{\d}{\text{d}}
\newcommand{\D}{\text{D}}
\newcommand{\bra}{\langle}
\newcommand{\ket}{\rangle}

\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}

\newcommand{\p}{\partial}
\newcommand{\eq}[1]{\begin{align*}#1\end{align*}}

\begin{document}

\noindent \fbox{
\begin{minipage}{6.4in}
  \medskip
  \textbf{Book} \hfill \textbf{Author}
  \begin{center}
    {\Large Chapter \#} \\[3mm]
  \end{center}
\today \hfill Subauthor
\medskip
\end{minipage}
}

\bigskip
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{}
\subsection{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `combine` package may help. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119415/trying-to-create-simple-template-for-novice-users/119873#119873. You could also consider a master document with `include` and  `includeonly`.

Comment: Doesn't that still require that I build up my preamble manually?

Comment: Both the methods I suggested above allow you to create a preamble once and use it in several contexts.

Comment: But this is not what I need though. The preamble might vary across chapters, and when I compile a single chapter - it will have its own table of contents. There should be a global table of contents when I compile all chapters at once, rather than individual ones. `\include` and `\includeonly` will allow for a global preamble, but I can only compile a master document, not individual ones.

Comment: Look at the `combine` package http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/combine/combine.pdf. It should be flexible enough to meet your needs.

Comment: I've done this many times. I'look around for document I wrote on this, and try to add it here. I use a number of Martin Scharrer`s packages and the import package.

Answer (score 4):

There are packages to do that kind of combination but if you are worried about unknown artefacts from the command redefinitions you can simply use

```
\ifx\p\undefined
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
```

.
   .
   .

```
\fi
\begin{document}
```

Then when processed on its own the document will work as normal but in a larger document that already has those definitions loaded (and in particular `\p` defined you can use

```
{\def\document{}\def\enddocument{}\input{file-1}}
```

Not related to the inclusion question but the boxed heading is lager than the page:

```
Overfull \hbox (36.87251pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 29--40
```

Answer (score 1):

The [subfiles package](https://ctan.org/pkg/subfiles) does exactly what you are looking for. There are is a great [documentation on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multi-file_LaTeX_projects#The_subfiles_package) even with live examples. The main document includes the child files as this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{subfiles}
% global preamble
\begin{document}
\subfile{childA}
\subfile{childB}
\subfile{childC}
\end{document}
```

The child files can be compiled individually and even have their own preamble.

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
% individual preamble
\begin{document}
content
\end{document}
```

Also cross-references between the files are supported.